Is this an umlaut above a y in this 1922 Patronatsschein?
In this Patronatsschein for the Bayreuther Festspiele from 1922, there appears to be an umlaut over the y in "Bayreuth" each of the three times it is written:

Is there a historical explanation for this, and/or was it a practice made obsolete through a spelling reform, etc.?

The whole letters ÄÖÜ/ääü are called "Umlaut", it's not a part of the letter. What's above the letter ÄÖÜ etc is called 'dots', or 'Punkte' in German.

@userunknown: the "dots" (and other similar additions to letters) are called "diacriticals" (diakritische Zeichen).

@userunknown: In English terminology for German orthography, umlaut is the standard name for this diacritic.  It’s different from the German terminology, but it’s perfectly correct in English.  (And even in German, Wikipedia tells me that the diacritic can be called Umlautpunkte, among several other names.)

@bakunin Most commonly diacritics rather than diacriticals – while diacritic is both a noun and an adjective, diacritical is rare as a noun.

@userunknown Umlaut is strictly speaking neither a diacritic nor a letter, but the historical phonological process that, in German, turned /a o u/ into /ε œ y/ before syllables containing /i/ (i-umlaut). The word is varyingly used in an extended sense in different languages to refer to the sounds resulting from that process (German Umlaute, English umlauted sound), any diacritic that indicates this result (German Umlautzeichen, English umlaut), or even any letter that includes such a diacritic (German Umlaut, English letter with umlaut).

@JanusBahsJacquet: thank you for the clarification "diacritic" vs. "diacritical". I stand corrected. I only knew the German phrase and translated it "freehand" - I should not do this.

@PLL Umlautpunkte sind in erster Linie Punkte, aber nicht Umlaute, sowenig wie ein I-Punkt ein I ist oder eine Fahrradglocke eine Glocke ist, kein Fahrrad. Mir war nicht bewusst, dass umlaut als englischer Term nicht das ganze Zeichen, sondern die Punkte bezeichnen kann.

Short answer:
This is an old method to indicate that the vowel i has to be spoken long. This method became extinct and is no longer a valid method in German.

Answer with more details:
In German, some vowels must be pronounced longer than usual. In fact, sometimes the length of a spoken vowel is the only thing that distinguishes two words that would sound identical if all vowels had the same length.

Miete [ˈmiːtə] = rent
Mitte [ˈmɪtə] = center

To indicate the length of a spoken vowel in a written word, there are several techniques. One of the most commonly used techniques is to double the vowel:

Saat, Beet, Boot

This is not the case for i and u. If there are two u's or two i's next to each other in a word, they belong to two different syllables and are spoken separately. (Examples: Genugtuung, zuunterst, Multiinstrumentalist, Skiindustrie.) The same is true for umlauts (there are no double umlauts in German words), although I couldn't find an example of a German word where two umlauts (belonging to two different syllables) exist next to each other.
The only way to indicate that the vowel u or an umlaut must be spoken long is to add a Dehnungs-H (stretching h). This Dehnungs-H (sometimes called »stummes H« = silent h) works after all vowels (a, ä, e, i, o, ö, u and ü):

Stahl, während, Mehl, ihm, Sohn, Höhle, Stuhl, Gefühl

However, the letter i used to have two additional methods, of which only the "Dehnungs-E" (stretching e) survived, while the "Dehnungs-J" (stretching j) became extinct.
The Dehnungs-E is well known and can be found in thousands of German words (die, wie, sie, vier, Spiel, Liebe, ...), and the combination ie is often called »langes I« (long i). (Note that the letters i and e can also belong to two different syllables, in which case they are spoken as two separate vowels: offiziell, Patient, Karriere, ...)
The letter j, although a consonant, is pronounced very similarly to the vowel i. Until the early years of the 20th century, both the letters i and j were used to write the spoken vowel i, and both were also used to write the spoken consonant j. (An example is the spelling »Jnselplatz« of a place pronounced »Inselplatz« in the German city of Jena. Wikimedia has an image showing this street sign.)
So in German, j was a twin of i, and instead of doubling the letter i to indicate a long pronunciation, a j was inserted after the i. Another reason for writing j after i was the Latin genitive case of some words, which was used in some situations in the past:

Quintus Februarij (instead of ... Februarii) (Februar 5)
Ecclesia Sancti Georgij (instead of ... Georgii) (Church of St. George)

But in German handwriting, i followed by j looks exactly like ÿ: Februarÿ, Georgÿ and also Baÿreuth. The combination ij was preferred to ii because in handwriting ii looks identical to ü, which is a common letter in many German words, while in handwriting ij looks like ÿ, which does not exist as such in German words, and was therefore always interpreted as ij, i.e. as a long spoken i.

The Latin genitive case disappeared more and more in German texts, and the dots on the letter ÿ, which came from i and j, also disappeared, and so the letter y (without dots) became part of the German alphabet. Even I (born in Austria in 1965) did not learn the name »Ypsilon« for this letter in school, but »Fremdes I« (foreign i), because in German words it is pronounced like the letter i. The name of the city »Ybbs und der Donau« (in Austria) is pronounced »Ibbs ...«, and also in names like »Bayern« or »Bayreuth« it is used and pronounced like i. (Although how »Bayern« got its y is a completely different story, which also tells how the Greek national flag got its colors, but it's too long to tell here. Nevertheless, the y in Bayern is pronounced as if it were written »Baiern«).

Addendum:
Every year at the end of July, I perform as a member of a choir in the collegiate church of the Benedictine monastery of Melk (Wikipedia), as I did two days ago. To avoid having to walk through the audience when we appear, the abbot of the monastery allows us to pass through the cloister, i.e. the part of the monastery that is not open to the public. As we were waiting to enter the church before the final rehearsal, I noticed this memorial plaque set into the walls of the cloister:

It is a memorial plaque from 1658, which the sons of a deceased baron had made in memory of their father. The spelling of the word "OBSEQUII" (bottom right of the plaque) is interesting:

The sequence of letters "II" (actually "İİ") was written as an İJ̇ ligature, which looks like "Ÿ", as was frequently practiced at the time.
Such Latin inscription tablets with İJ̇ ligature can be found throughout the German-speaking world, and the design of the letters on these tablets had a great influence on the typography of the German language, as already mentioned above.

This is interesting; I was born in 1966 (in Germany) and this is the first time I hear about "Fremdes I".

@GuntramBlohm: I noticed, that the name »Fremdes I« was only used in Austria. I believe, that it also might be known in Bavaria, but in Austria this name was taught in school, but as far as I know today only the name »Ypsilon« is taught.

I couldn't find any example of a German word where two umlauts (belonging to two different syllables) exist side by side. "Der Malmöösterreicher erholt sich noch von seiner Mittagsmenüübelkeit." Yes, I know, using compound nouns is cheating. Still, I challenge the german.se community to find a compound noun with "ää" that actually makes sense.

@Heinzi There's a journalist at Deutschlandfunk with the Name Ann-Kathrin Büüsker, but of course names are cheating, too.

@Heinzi A hypothetical catholic holiday "Mariä Ärgernis" ?  There is a dearth of words ending in Ä. If you find one, a compound XXX-Ära should be viable.
As for the way to write y/ij: I had not heard about this in German, but the ij persists in Dutch.

@Heinzi maybe some creating Eindeutschung of some techno-speak. "The new software is still in the pre-change stage" - "Die neue Software is noch in der Prä-Änderungsphase".

Is there a reason why you spell at one point "Beÿreuth" instead of "Baÿreuth"?

Absolutely incredible and pedagogical answer, and I experienced "But in German handwriting, i followed by j looks just like ÿ" like a plot twist in a great novel. Thank you!

@ccprog: Yes, there is a reason: It was a typo. I have now revised the entire text of my reply and have (hopefully) corrected all the typos.

Regarding the assertion about the dots on the letter ÿ, which came from i and j, Ebert et al. (1993), Frühneuhochdeutsche Grammatik, states: "y wird häufig mit Diakritika versehen (ẏ~ÿ, seltener ý). Ob hier ein graphischer Reflex der Ligaturschreibung von ij vorliegt, ist schwer zu entscheiden." They point out that other diacritics were used as well. Secondly, y was used for both long and short i, in diphthongs in place of i, for long and short ü, j and even as a lengthening mark (similar to i in Troisdorf).

Do I understand right that Bayreuth was once pronounced with a long i-sound?

@Heinzi Using foreign words is also cheating, and to be extra pedantic, in Swedish the ö is not considered o-umlaut, but a letter in its own right (substituting Malmö for Malmoe, as Germans might be tempted to do if they cannot use the ö for technical reasons, is invalid), unless one argues that Malmö (with o-Umlaut) is the German spelling for Malmö (with the letter ö) — one can have a lovingly pedantic debate whether Malmööstereicher (whatever that even means) even counts :)

Re double umlaut: in Swiss German there is the Böögg - zuerich.com/en/visit/sechselaeuten/who-or-what-is-the-boeoegg - burnt at “Sechseläuten” or in local dialect “Sächsilüüte” (another double umlaut)

@Heinzi Herausforderung akzeptiert! Hätte "präägyptisch" und "Tätärätä-Ächtung" im Angebot :D Zumindest zweiteres ist natürlich etwas weiter hergeholt, aber leider gibt es kaum Wörter die auf "ä" enden. "Ä" am Wortanfang ist nicht der Flaschenhals. Mit "prä" könnte man wahrscheinlich noch ein paar mehr Kombinationen bilden, aber das durchzuspielen ist mMn nicht mehr so interessant.

@gerrit Even though ö is a distinct letter of the alphabet in Swedish, it can still often be considered a form of umlaut, since the Swedish diacritic (borrowed from German) also indicates that the sound is the result of an umlauting process on some level. Of course, in the word ö ‘island’ (Malm-ö = Ore Island), the /øː/ sound is due primarily to monophthongisation of ON ey, which in turn is i-umlauted from au, so it’s a bit more complicated whether this instance would be umlaut or not.

See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#Ligatur_ij
Summary: There are words in which an original combination of the letters "ij" was written as "y", and therefore the dots were retained. So "y" with two dots was used to signal a "German y", instead of a letter y that is of Greek origin.
(Nowadays, this is no longer possible).

Dutch also uses y for the ij combination.
